# Optmizing print code when writing to file, and reducing print time

Tags: arduino-mega

First things first, I have found some solutions to this problems but they all involved for printing to serial monitor. I am trying to take the information from the sensors and write them to an sd card. Here is my code so far:

```
//-----Writes Data to SD Card-----//
if(!Data) {
    u8g.firstPage();  
    do {
       drawFileError();
    } while( u8g.nextPage() );
    while (1);  // don't do anything more:
} 

dcounter++;
if (dcounter=1){

    Data = SD.open("Data.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRITE);
    Data.println(Header);
    Data.print(strutcDate + "  ");
    Data.print(strutcTime + "  ");
    Data.print(strgpsStatus + "  ");
    Data.print(strmodeIndicator + "  ");
    Data.print(strlatitude + "  ");
    Data.print(strlongitude + "  ");
    Data.print(strspeedOverGnd + "  ");
    Data.print(strcourseOverGnd + "  ");
    Data.print(t);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.print(f);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.print(h);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.print(hi);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.print(press_pKa);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.println(str);
    Data.close();
} else{
    Data.print(strutcDate + "  ");
    Data.print(strutcTime + "  ");
    Data.print(strgpsStatus + "  ");
    Data.print(strmodeIndicator + "  ");
    Data.print(strlatitude + "  ");
    Data.print(strlongitude + "  ");
    Data.print(strspeedOverGnd + "  ");
    Data.print(strcourseOverGnd + "  ");
    Data.print(t);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.print(f);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.print(h);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.print(hi);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.print(press_pKa);
    Data.print("  ");
    Data.println(str);
    Data.close();
}
```

two questions: is it possible for me to reduce this chunk of code into something smaller? is there a way to decrease print time?

Edit: Ahh I see, the problem with my code is that the last few values are floats.Any way to shorten those as well, or do i need to do it individually? I do agree about the adding string parts.

Comment: Several Arduino libraries for talking to SD cards are listed at http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/InterfacingWithHardware#Storage . Perhaps one of them is faster than the library you are using now?

Comment: Edit you question to state how long it is currently taking to print and what sort of improvements you need.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the only difference between the two parts of the "if" statement is that, the first time, it prints the header. Instead of that code, you could do this:

```
//(Include the top part of the code here...)    
dcounter++;
if (dcounter=1){
    Data = SD.open("Data.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRITE);
    Data.println(Header);
}
Data.print(strutcDate + "  ");
Data.print(strutcTime + "  ");
Data.print(strgpsStatus + "  ");
Data.print(strmodeIndicator + "  ");
Data.print(strlatitude + "  ");
Data.print(strlongitude + "  ");
Data.print(strspeedOverGnd + "  ");
Data.print(strcourseOverGnd + "  ");
Data.print(t);
Data.print("  ");
Data.print(f);
Data.print("  ");
Data.print(h);
Data.print("  ");
Data.print(hi);
Data.print("  ");
Data.print(press_pKa);
Data.print("  ");
Data.println(str);
Data.close();
```

Like already mentioned, you can append strings with the `+` operator. This would be the final code then:

```
//(Include the top part of the code here...)
dcounter++;
if (dcounter=1){
    Data = SD.open("Data.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRITE);
    Data.println(Header);
}
Data.println(strutcDate + " " + strutcTime + "  " + strgpsStatus + "  " + strmodeIndicator + "  " + strlatitude + "  " + strlongitude + "  " + strspeedOverGnd + "  " + strcourseOverGnd + "  " + t + "  " + f + "  " + h + "  " + hi + "  " + press_pKa + "  " + str);
Data.close();
```

FYI, it doesn't seem like you should close the stream every iteration at the end since you only open it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I would analize what I want to write, extrapolate all numeric value, then create a structure that hold numeric value. So at every write I would write the structure (it is a binary write, so use fixed byte size) followed by all others string(or even place string in different file, but may turn out harder to manipulate or fix in case of problem).

Then to read it you'll need to read back the structure, followed by eventual know number of string. If string may be of unknown number,, just put the number of following string into the struct. Outside string, as you can see, you need no special char to signal the end of chunk of data :)

Unrelated: please, remove all println in the if rather than the header as they are equal to the else; then remove the else statement (but not the else body!) That way the if will open file and add header, and then the code will always add the rest of code. It would be a shame if you edit your else branch and forgot the if, or viceversa. Code style matters, trust me

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps with speed. It will however use more memory, so use with caution.

```
Data.println(Header);
Data.println(strutcDate + " " + strutcTime + "  " + strgpsStatus + "  " + strmodeIndicator + "  " + strlatitude + "  " + strlongitude + "  " + strspeedOverGnd + "  " + strcourseOverGnd + "  " + t + "  " + f + "  " + h + "  " + hi + "  " + press_pKa + "  " + str);
Data.close();
```

Comment: As you suggest yourself, don't ever do code like this on a microcontroller.  This is a likely to overflow the stack.